# what is big deal deploying debug build in production

Tags: release, debug-symbols

Given that 90% of time, developers are working with debug builds, why, exactly, is deploying release builds preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Size, speed, and memory use.**

Your users aren't going to need all the debugging crud you work with, so stripping the debug symbols reduces binary size and memory consumption (and therefore increases speed, as less time is spent loading the program's components into RAM).

When your application crashes, you usually want a traceback and the details. Your users really couldn't care less about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with deploying a debug build.  People commonly don't because non-debug builds tend to be more efficient (i.e. the assertion code is removed and the compiler doesn't insert tracing/debugger info in the object code).

Answer (score 0):

With Java 1.1, the debug builds could be much slower and they needed more disk space (at that time, disk with 120 *megabytes* were **huge** - try to fit your home directory on such a small device...).

Today, both are not an issue anymore. The Java runtime ignored debug symbols and with the JIT, the code is optimized at runtime so the compile time optimizations don't mean that much anymore.

One big advantage of debug builds is that the code in production is exactly what you tested.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on the build configuration, which may have compilation optimisations when doing a "release" build. There are other considerations, dependant on language; for example, when compiling an application using Visual C++, you can compile against debug versions of the C RunTime (CRT), which you are not permitted to redistribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is determine what exactly makes a build a "debug build". Mainly production builds are more optimized (memory usage, performance, etc.), and more care has been taken to build it in such a way that makes it easier to deploy and maintain. One main thing that I run into the most is that debug builds have a lot of unneeded logging that results in a pretty dramatic performance hit.

Apart from that, there is no real reason why debug builds shouldn't be deployed to production environments.